# Magento 2 : How to redirect Home page URL to your Custom module action

Tags: magento-2.1, redirect, home

How to redirect to my custom route (i mean whats the best way) ?

Comment: You can use Url rewrite feature in magento 2. admin login >> Marketing >> Url rewrite >> add new URL rewrite. Here you can add your custom URL rewrite.

Answer (score 1):

On the Admin panel, click `Stores->Settings->Configuration->Web->General` in the panel on the left.
Open the `Default Pages` section. Change the `Default Web URL` to the URL of your custom module.

Answer (score 0):

I think this will work for you

https://github.com/zoransalamun/magento2-custom-router

You can make check if home page is requested. And set your custom module and controller name from Router.php controller.

And when trying to test the module please take care of this line

> $request->setModuleName('cms')->setControllerName('page')->setActionName('view')->setParam('page_id', 5);

Here 5 is the page id and some times you don't have any page in your store with page id 5 , so you have to replace it with available page id.